# template input and template reference variable in a template

Tags: angular

We create template input variable using let keyword while we create template reference variable using #var where var is the name of the variable. 
We can refer to a template reference variable anywhere in the template.

What about the scope of the template input variable? How does it differ from scope of template reference variable? Can someone help me to understand with examples?

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.name}}</div> <!--hero is template input variable-->
<input #heroInput> {{heroInput.value}} <!--heroInput is template reference variable-->
```

Comment: is there anything unclear about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45785225/2545680)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: you are welcome, good luck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### template context variable

When the compiler parses `ng-template` element contents it identifies `let-tplVar="ctxValue"` tokens and creates a binding:

```
[variable that can be used inside the template] = "context variable"
[tplVar]                                        = "ctxValue"
```

Context template variable can be used anywhere inside the template. So for `ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.name}}</div>
```

the `hero` variable will be available inside the `ng-template`:

```
<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="heroes" let-hero="$implicit">
  <div>{{hero.name}}</div>
```

#### template variable

When compiler parses component template it creates binding for template variables and they can be accessed anywhere inside the template of the component:

```
<input #heroInput>
<span>{{heroInput.value}}</span>
```

You can also use template binding inside the `ngFor`:

```
<input #heroInput>
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.name}} and {{heroInput.value}}</div>
```

Even though it is not provided in the template context by `ngFor` the compiler generates the following [updateRenderer](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d) function:

```
  function(_ck,_v) {
      var currVal_0 = _v.context.$implicit.name;         <---- read from context
      var currVal_1 = jit_nodeValue4(_v.parent,4).value; <---- read from template variable
      _ck(_v,1,0,currVal_0,currVal_1);
  });
```

Comment: what if inside the *ngFor you create more inputs with the same template variable #heroInput ?