# Angular 8 template reference variable scope unclear

Tags: html, angular

I have given a name using the `#var` notation to an angular component (`app-backtester-chart`) created by me, but I don't understand why I don't seem to be able to reference it outside of the `div` it is in?
I'm clearly missing something here...

```
  {{chartcmp.width}}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" *ngIf="thisStrategy">
      {{chartcmp.width}}
      <app-backtester-chart #chartcmp
                          [inputStrategy]="thisStrategy"
                          [showBenchmark]="showBenchmark">
      </app-backtester-chart>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The first `{{chartcmp.width}}` generates an error: `Cannot read property 'width' of undefined`

So why does the second one inside the `div` works, and correctly displays the width?

From the Angular documentation ([Template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)):

> You can refer to a template reference variable anywhere in the component's template.

I can't find an explanation anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your `*ngIf` if you're doing an `ngIf`  all div inside are not constructed as well as your variable ^^

Comment: Ok, removing the *ngIf it works, so thanks for that, but I still don't get the rationale. If the condition of the *ngIf evaluates to "true" then what's inside it gets constructed, which is exactly what happens in my code. So why would the variable not exist outside of it? Is its scope limited by the existence of the *ngIf, like in C# for example what is inside the curly brackets defines a new scope? I can't find a clear answer anywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782524/template-input-and-template-reference-variable-in-a-template

Answer (score 2):

It's beacause of the `*ngIf`. You can't access a template reference variable if it's not rendred.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for first one

```
{{chartcmp === null? "" : chartcmp.width}}
```